# HERE Maps SearchBox not working on Firefox older version (eg. 12)

Tags: javascript, json, debugging, here-api, firefox-12

I'm trying to get HERE Maps working on Firefox 12 and I'm having troubles with the SearchBox component, in particular clicking on a search result.

After a little debug, I found that the jsPlacesAPI.js remote script throws an error at this point:

```
var b=t.parse(s.getItem(u))||{};
```

This causes an error because `u` is `nokia.places.suggestions` and `s.getItem(u)` returns an empty string.

Obviously, `t.parse('')` fails because the empty string is not valid JSON.

This works like a charm in the latest Firefox, Chrome and IE8+.

Any suggestion, apart from updating FF?

Answer (score 1):

> The only way to make it works was to hack the json2.js script in order to not throw an exception on parsing ''.